# Why does it state that *-cache:1 DISABLED at lshw command

Tags: ram

It seems like my memory is working correctly but I am puzzled by the output of the following command. Is the memory disabled and how do I go about testing it if it may be.

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware              
   description: BIOS
   vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
   physical id: 0
   version: Version 07.00T
   date: 04/02/01
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 448KiB
   capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int17printer int10video acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
*-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 5
   slot: Internal Cache
   size: 48KiB
   capacity: 1MiB
   capabilities: pipeline-burst synchronous internal write-back data
*-cache:1 DISABLED
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 6
   slot: Internal Cache
   size: 1MiB
   capacity: 1MiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
*-memory
   description: System memory
   physical id: 1
   size: 1508MiB
```